# Differential equations: How do I solve a delay differential equation with 0-1 variables

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

How do I solve the following non-linear, delay-differential equations using *Mathematica* under the assumptions
 $$p(t) = 1 ,\; y(t) > k$$  $$p(t) = 0,\; y(t)<= \ k$$.
$$
\frac{dw}{dt}  = \frac{1}{R(t)} - \frac{w(t)x(t)}{2R(t)}p(t-D),
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}  = \frac{g}{R(t)}(p(t-D)-x(t)),
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}  = N\frac{w(t)}{R(t)} - c
$$
$$
D = d + k/c, 
$$
$$
R(t) = d + y(t)/c
$$

$$g,N,c,d,k \; are \; constants$$

Below is the code I wrote for it. I'm getting some errors which are listed just after the code.

Cell1

```
Clear["Global`*"];
w0 = 1500 * 8; x0 = 0; y0 = 0; p0 = 0; 
g = 1/16; k = 65 * w0; c = 10000*10^6; d = 100 * 10^-6; n = 20;
```

Cell2

```
r[t] = y[t]/c + d;
D0 = k/c + d;
ics = {w[t /; t <= 0] == w0, x[t /; t <= 0] == x0, 
y[t /; t <= 0] == y0, p[t /; t <= 0] == 0};
eqs = {w'[t] == 1/r[t] - (p[t - D0] (w[t] x[t]))/(2 r[t]), 
x'[t] == (g (p[t - D0] - x[t]))/r[t], 
y'[t] == n (w[t]/r[t] - c), p'[t] == 0, 
WhenEvent[{y[t] > k, p[t] -> 1,"IntegrateEvent" -> True},
{y[t] < 0, y[t] -> 0, "IntegrateEvent" -> True}; 
If[y[t] < 0, y[t] -> 0]; 
If[y[t] <= k, p[t] -> 0]], ics};
```

Cell3

```
sol1 = NDSolve[
eqs, {w[t], x[t], y[t], w'[t], x'[t], y'[t]}, {t, 0, 3}, 
MaxSteps -> 100000];
```

Cell4

```
Plot[Evaluate[{w[t], x[t], y[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: First, do not use uppercase (esp. single-letter) names, which may well be already in use by the system. `N` , `C` e.g. are protected symbols (see the help).

Comment: I just did the corrections, here the error message I'm getting when I try to run the code.  NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {p[t],w[t],x[t],y[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined. >>

Comment: @Nasser, I have adjusted it the show the complete code.

Comment: There is no syntax error now.

Comment: @Nasser thanks, I'd do just that.

Comment: So I did exactly what you asked me to do. Now I'm getting this error message: NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Comment: I have updated it with the minimal code. U can try and execute that now. Thanks

Comment: @Nasser I already corrected the `WhenEvent` Syntax but I didn't update it here, for `R[t]` blowing up, I don't think there is a problem with the equation as `R[t]` has a second term `d` which is a constant. Can we possibly go off here for a lil bit and have a real time chat?

Comment: oh yes, I did not see the constant. But the problem seems to be with the IC. But I really have to go now work on my HW (hard HW ;), will have another look tomorrow if I can. But good you cleaned the code, it is easier to see now. May be someone else will look at it.

Comment: Aight thanks for your help. I did some adjustments and I'm beginning to see plots for the first time. Though the plots didn't look like what I was expecting, I think all that is left now is for me to fine tune the initial conditions and parameters. Once again thanks for your help

Comment: Consider using `p[t_] = 1 - UnitStep[y[t] - k]` instead of `WhenEvent`.

Comment: @Nasser and @MichaelE2, I did what Michael recommended still no results. I modified the code differently and somehow I'm beginning to see plots, but these are not consistent with the result I was expecting (All the dependent variables `x,y,w` should produce sawtooth-like plots). I also observed that `y' becomes negative from its zero initial value, I don't want this to happen i.e if y is going to be negative, then it should be replaced with 0 (y is only zero or positive). How do I include this in my code? thanks guys

Comment: @Nasser, Are those errors or warning messages? Besides I don't have any ideas of what those messages mean..

Comment: @MichaelE2, can you please help in figuring out the error messages too? thanks.